# Number for each enum item?

Tags: java, integer, enums, bit-manipulation

Is it possible to define something like this in java?

C# code:

```
public enum Character
{
    A = 1,

    B = 2,

    C = 4,

    D = 8

}


...

Character ch = /* from user */

if(ch & Character.A)
{
    // some operation...
}
```

for example if `ch` set to `Character.B` then result of `if` will be `false`:

```
ch = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
A  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
------------------------------------------
&    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

I want to implement something like that! Is it ever possible in Java?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, you can *nearly* do that:

```
public enum CharEnum // Let's avoid java.lang.* clashes
{
    A(1), B(2), C(4), D(8);

    private final int mask;

    private CharEnum(int mask)
    {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public int getMask()
    {
        return mask;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
CharEnum ch = /* from user */

if ((ch.getMask() & CharEnum.A.getMask()) > 0)
{
    // some operation...
}
```

This can be useful in some situations, but as Michael said you should definitely look at [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for general "set of values" options.

If you *do* decide to go for an enum with values, you can put extra logic within the enum itself:

```
public enum CharEnum
{
    // Other code as before

    public boolean overlapsWith(CharEnum ch)
    {
        return (ch.mask & mask) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some parenthesis there: `if ((ch.getMask() & CharEnum.A.getMask()) > 0)`

Answer (score 5):

(Of course, choosing `Character` as the name of your enum is very confusing as it creates a conflict with `java.lang.Character` which is automatically imported into every compilation unit)

You can use the ordinal() method to get the integer associated with an enum constant. Anyway, I got a feeling that what you are trying to achieve may be realized by enum-defined methods. I mean, Java's enum are more powerful than C/C++'s because you can associate behavior with them.

```
  public enum Chr {
    A {
       @Override public void doSomething(int c) {
         // some operation ...
       }
    },
    B,
    C,
    D;

    public void doSomething(int c) { 
      // some default behavior
    }
  }
```

Following your comment:

You can define a field which will hold this value, and have the constructor initialize it, as follows:

```
  public enum Chr {
    A(1),
    B(2),
    C(4),
    D(8)
    ;

    public Chr(int n) { value = n; }        
    public final int value;
  }



  Character ch = ... // from user
  if(ch & Chr.A.value) {
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that using `Enum.ordinal()`, but it would be really bad design. You should use `==` for equality comparisons and [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for set operations.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Itay, and to get a bit further I'll recommend the reading of **[Effective Java Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/index.html)** having a full chapter really interesting on Java enums.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Michael Borgwardt and Jon Skeet that an `EnumSet` is worth looking at. I would have picked `EnumSet` over bitwise operations like you've got, so I will demonstrate how to use `EnumSet`.

It looks like your <strike>`Character` enum</strike> (let's call it `CharEnum` from now on) `CharEnum` is being used like a bit field, where each enum has an int value with just one bit set:

```
A  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
B  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
C  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
D  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000
```

This is very similar to what an `EnumSet` does for you; it has an internal bit vector that automatically assigns each enum to a bit on a `long`. As the JavaDoc for it says, *"The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags."*

Here's an example of how to use it

```
public enum CharEnum {
    A, B, C, D;
}
```

and then

```
EnumSet<CharEnum> ch = /* from user */

if (ch.contains(CharEnum.A)) {
    // some operation...
}
```

No need to specify bits anywhere, so it's much simpler code!

**A warning:** this only works because the enum values in your C# example have only one bit set each. If you had an enum value like this:

```
E  = 00011000 01110111 11100101 10000101
```

then an `EnumSet` would not be appropriate. In that case you should look at one of the other answers here.