# Object Instance Manipulation

Tags: java, string, object

If I have an Object instance, say a4, is there a way I could print out the name of the instance?

So with the instance a4, I would like my output to say a4.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838454/can-i-print-out-the-name-of-the-variable

Comment: Use Java reflection API.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: instance means if you are having an objec of type String you want to print String, is that it ??

Comment: +1 for "Why the hell do you want to do that?" It would help us help you.

Comment: Instances do not have a name! Variables do, though.

Comment: I'm looking to place an array in a HashMap using the name of the variable as the key.

Comment: If you have a method, and inside that you have a variable declaration _Object[] myArray;_ (for example), then you already know the variable name. So, what exactly is your problem? It is not clear to me. Maybe you should post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is; if you want an object to have a name, give it a `name` field and add this field to the `toString()`

---

Local variables are only available in the debug information of a method.  It is possible to read the byte code of a method and reverse engineer a name but this requires an extraordinary amount of work.

Consider

```
Object a1 = ...
Object b1 = a1;
```

The same object is referenced by two local variables.  An object can be referenced in any number of places. e.g the empty string object is often the most referenced object in a Java program.  It can appear in 10Ks places in a normal program.

---

> I'm trying to add an array to a HashMap using a method that is only passed in a HashMap key. I take the key, extract an array already in the HashMap, make a clone of it, and then place that clone in the HashMap using the name of the instance as the key.

Say you pass an array into a method like

```
public void addArray(int... array) {
```

At this point the "name" of the reference to the array is `array` and it will not be anything difference.

What you need is to pass the name you want the array to have as there is no way for a caller to know what the callee used as a local variable.  Often a variable has no name in the first place.

```
addArray(1, 2, 3);
```

or

```
addArray(calculateNumbers());
```

or

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3 };
addArray(nums);
```

Note: `nums` is not actually needed as a local variable can be optimised away. i.e. There is a good chance `nums` won't even exist at runtime.

---

What you need to do is

```
public void addArray(String name, int... array) {
    map.put(name, array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not stalking you I swear!

Short answer: No

Long Answer: Its impossible to get the name of a local variable using the reflection API as it is simply not available to the JVM. Have a look here: [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Its a hideously messy thing to attempt to do. Why are you trying to do it?

Comment: I'm trying to add an array to a HashMap using a method that is only passed in a HashMap key. I take the key, extract an array already in the HashMap, make a clone of it, and then place that clone in the HashMap using the name of the instance as the key.

Comment: can you post your code? This is a design problem that's tricky to conceptualise. But why don't you just place the array in the hash map with the instance name as the key in the first place? Do you have to clone the array?