# Enum in Java like in C#

Tags: java, c#

I would like to have somethimng

```
public enum CategoryTypes 
{
        Unknown = 0,
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
}
```

in Java? So it could be possible to cast Int to value and vise versa.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
int i = Fruit.GRAPE.ordinal() ;  // Beware: Horrible misnomer; actually a zero-based index rather than an ordinal.
```

…and…

```
Fruit f = Fruit.values()[i] ;
```

**But do not do this!** Read on for details.

## Java `Enum`

Java provides a vastly more useful, flexible, and powerful version of enums.

See:

- [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class

Can be as simple as:

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLE , 
    ORANGE , 
    GRAPE
}
```

To use it:

```
Fruit f = Fruit.APPLE ;
```

Usually we have no need for the underlying integer number representing the order in which the elements were defined for the enum. Instead we just use each element of the enum as a normal Java object rather than juggling a mere int number. But if you insist:

- Call `Enum::ordinal` to retrieve the a zero-based index number (this method is a terrible misnomer as it is an index rather than a one-based ordinal)
  `int i = Fruit.GRAPE.ordinal() ;`
- Call `Enum::values` to generate an array which you can access by zero-based index
  `Fruit f = Fruit.values()[i] ;`

In doing so, almost certainly **you would be failing to take advantage of the full power of the Java enum** facility. Using the actual enum objects rather than a mere `int` gives you type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

If your intent is to assign a meaningful code number to each enum instance, do so explicitly by defining a member variable populated by constructor taking that code number, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811815/is-it-possible-to-assign-numeric-value-to-an-enum-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3360283).

You can add methods and even add constructors taking arguments. Even more to it: [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) are specialized collections optimized for very little memory and very fast execution.

```
Set< Fruit > favoriteFruits = EnumSet.of( Fruit.APPLE , Fruit.ORANGE ) ;
```

Oddly, the `EnumSet` does not implement `SortedSet`, yet it is documented as returning instances in the order of their enum definition.

Search Stack Overflow for many more discussions and examples.

For a prime example of `Enum` in action, see:

- [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)
- [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html)

Comment: In C# we can set like One = 1234. I mean any int number. From your example it is not clear how to do it... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer See my edits. I explain that once you grok Java enum, you'll likely never utilize the underlying ordinal integer number. But if you insist, you'll find such code in my Answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Enums in Java are actually classes Singleton instances of the class represented by the enum you created. For the instances to have values, you need to store it in the class, and create a private constructor to set them. Also a getter method would be nice. For example:

```
  public enum MyEnum {
      INSTANCE(5),
      N2(2);

     private int member;
     private MyEnum(int member) {
       this.member = member;
     }
  }
```